# Want to remove sku from order email in mangento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I would like to remove an `SKU` from my order email.  I already have tried one method, which I found at StackOverflow:

In `sales.xml` check the `sales_email_order_items` block and edit all the template form it (`default.phtml` and `items.phtml`).

However, I'm unable to remove it from order email.

Answer (score 0):

You should comment out

```
<th align="left" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->__('Sku') ?></th>
```

line in `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/item.phtml`.

and

```
<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getSku($_item)) ?></td>
```

line in `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/items/order/default.phtml`